# Is there any way to install Jenkins plugin using puppet?

Tags: jenkins, puppet, gerrit

I am trying to find out a way to install Jenkins plugin using puppet. I would like to create a Gerrit patch then to install it and to revert the patch in case it is required. Is this achievable ?

```
--> Basically want to create a procedure to both upgrade and downgrade plugin
-->Manage Plugin install/upgrade using puppet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jenkins module supports plugins:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/puppet-jenkins/blob/master/manifests/plugin.pp

You can roll back and remove the plugin with `ensure => absent` or `version => <version`

Here's an example:

```
jenkins::plugin {
  'ansicolor' :
   version => '0.3.1';
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... This module will take care of plugin dependencies as well ?

Comment: No, you'll have to manage those separately. I would recommend wrapping your plugins in a profile and then chaining them using the chaining resource.